# What's the difference in since and from in "I've not seen her since/from August"

Tags: prepositions

Everywhere people have provided explanation for "since" vs "for" but what is the difference between **since** and **from**?

Another example:

> It has been raining from/since morning.

I know 'since' is right but why is 'from' wrong?

Comment: in my opinion, `from` is more about geographic positions, not about time (but i'm not native english)

Comment: I think the reason is simply that ***from*** has far more different meanings, so unless the context makes the *specific* figurative sense screamingly obvious, we're idiomatically programmed to avoid it. But it's fine in *It's been raining continuously **from** last night **right up until half-an-hour ago*** (where additional *text* supplies the extra context). Also in *We've been friends **from** childhood*, where no additional text is required.

Answer (score 1):

*Since* and *From* are used differently.  *Since* means from the reference point provided until now.

> He borrowed my lawnmower and I have not seen him since.

This means that whenever the lawnmower was taken until the moment the sentence was written (the present moment), the author has not seen the person who took the lawnmower.  It can also be written-

> I have not seen him since he borrowed my lawnmower.

*From* establishes a time frame that does not need to be tied to the present moment.  You would use it as follows.

> I did not see him from June 14 until August 5.

The *from* establishes a start point and an end point for the time frame.  These start and end points are often dates but they can be events too.  You can even mix events and dates.

> I did not see him from the time he borrowed my lawnmower until August the next summer.

As a few other posters have noted, *from* can be used to indicate a time frame extending to the present, if the sentence's tense implies that.  *We've been friends from childhood,* can be understood because the tense implies we are still friends.  This allows the sentence to be understood as, *We've been friends from childhood until now.*  I would suggest, however, that the sentence is better written, *We've been friends **since** childhood.*

Answer (score 0):

As you agree that 'since' is right here, I won't touch that part.

As Fumblefingers points out, "from" can be used in this kind of context, but to keep it simpler, we don't generally use it.

How can we use it? Because "from" also talks about some point of time, we often say, "he has been behaving like this from day one".

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'since' and 'from' are kind of similar though they have a difference in meaning, along with a distinct taste separating them. Sometimes a language is not about why this and why not that, it's about which one sounds better in that particular case.

But in this case, they also have a difference in meaning. 'Since' is used whenever the case has started and is still in an intermediate period. So it's the time between two particular incidents or times. However, 'from' is used for strict identification of time or place. It doesn't give you the intermediate sense or meaning of 'since'.