# Should I use "since" or "from" in sentence "they receive their religious education right since/from when they were kids"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

"They receive their religious education right from when they were kids"

Should I use "since" instead of "from"? Should it be "when they are/were kids"?

How can I improve this sentence?

Comment: EITHER use Present Tense throughout: *They **receive** their religious education right from when they **are** kids* (more naturally, *...right from **childhood***) OR use Past Tense throughout: *They **received** their religious education right from when they **were** kids.* You can use ***since*** in the Past Tense version, but not in the Present Tense version.

Comment: ^ thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of "since" and "from".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174423/usage-of-since-and-from) Also [Usage of 'from' and 'since'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52992/usage-of-from-and-since) and [What's the difference in since and from in "I've not seen her since/from August"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/whats-the-difference-in-since-and-from-in-ive-not-seen-her-since-from-august), among others.

Comment: are you talking about a specific group of kids, or are talking about kids in general.  Could you (in theory) name any of these kids?

Comment: Please do not cross post without mentioning your [original question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/611138/36710), which also had a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

You're beginning with "they *receive*", so it seems like you're making a generalisation rather than speaking about specific people (otherwise it would be "*received*" - past tense). If that's the case then you can't be referring to a specific starting point, and both "since" and "from when" are for referring to specific time points such as when a specific person was a 'kid'.

If you are wanting to speak generally, about all people in the context, then you could say:

> They receive* religious education right from childhood.

**or 'begin'*

But, if you are actually talking about some specific people referred to in the wider context, you could say:

> They **began** their religious education when they were kids.